# Making a clicked button redirect on to a particular page

Tags: c#, botframework

```
public virtual async Task ShowAnnuvalConferenceTicket(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
        {
            var message = await activity;

            PromptDialog.Choice(
                context: context,
                resume:ChoiceReceivedAsync ,
                options: (IEnumerable<ProductGroups>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProductGroups)),
                prompt: " ",
                promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
                );
        }
        public virtual async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<ProductGroups> activity)
        {
            ProductGroups response = await activity;
            context.Call<object>(new AnnualPlanDialog(response.ToString()), ChildDialogComplete);

        }
        public virtual async Task ChildDialogComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> response)
        {
            var respond = await response as Activity;
            if (respond = ProductGroups.MoreCategories)
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Click here to view more categories");
                context.Done(this);
            }

        }

public enum ProductGroups {
            Toys,
            Electronics,
            Phones,
            Health,
            Beauty,
            Computers,
            Cameras,
            Jewelery,
            Watches,
            Weddings,
            MoreCategories
        }
```

Good day, please I need help on these,I have been trying to get a list of options generated from enumerated constant each redirect me to different pages but know how to go about it. Any help please ?

Comment: what do you mean by redirect to different pages?

Comment: just like a link

Answer (score 6):

If you want to open a url then you can use [Hero Cards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards#hero-card) with just buttons. You can create a dictionary with the title and the link or you can also use the enum. Here's something I worked out with:

**Instead of sending Prompt**

```
var reply = context.MakeMessage();
List<CardAction> enumOptions = new List<CardAction>();
foreach(ProductGroups option in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProductGroups)))
{
    enumOptions.Add(new CardAction
    {
        Title = option.ToString(),
        Type = option.ToString().Equals("MoreCategories") ? ActionTypes.ImBack : ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
        Value = option.GetType()
                .GetMember(option.ToString())
                .First()
                .GetCustomAttribute<DescribeAttribute>()
                .Description
    });


}

reply.Attachments.Add(GetHeroCard(null, null, null, null, enumOptions));
await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

Type Attribute in CardAction will decide what to do when the button is clicked. So if the user clicked any button other than MoreCategories a link will open and if the user clicked MoreCategories the bot will get the message moreCategories and you can process it after that.

The GetHeroCard is just a basic function that you can call to create any hero card:

```
    public static Attachment GetHeroCard(string title, string subTitle, string text, List<CardImage> images, List<CardAction> action)
    {

        HeroCard card = new HeroCard();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            card.Title = title;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(subTitle))
            card.Subtitle = subTitle;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            card.Text = text;
        if (images != null)
            card.Images = images;
        if (action != null)
            card.Buttons =  action ;
        return card.ToAttachment();
    }
```

You can update your enum's like this:

```
public enum ProductGroups
{
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Toys,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Electronics,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Phones,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Health,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Beauty,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Computers,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Cameras,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Jewelery,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Watches,
    [Describe("https://stackoverflow.com/")]
    Weddings,
    [Describe("More categories")]
    MoreCategories
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]